# Filter an event and notify designated subscribers

Tags: c#, single-responsibility-principle

I'm new to TDD and I'm trying to apply Single Responsibility Principle to an API.

I'm using an API that returns multiple feed subscriptions in a single event. Each subscription can be differentiated from another because the Event Handler contains an **id** field. what I want to do is make a wrapper to the API which can manage the subscription updates such that a **Subscription** class only receives event updates relevant to it as determined by the **id** field of the event fired by the API.

Now I have wrapper to the API where I implemented the Subscribe() method such that it returns a **Subscription** class where it contains a **Subscription.Updated()** event. I keep a record of the **Subscription** s in a **Dictionary** so I can notify each **Subscription** based on their **id**.

My problem is how do I pass the Subscription Updated event parameters  from the API  to a particular **Subscription** and raise the **Subscription.Updated()** event? I've read that I can make a public OnUpdate method (which i've done in previous projects) but they say that this breaks encapsulation and SRP.

Or am I approaching this incorrectly? Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Additional info:

Request a feed from the API:
    `void Feed.Subscribe(id, SubscriptionParamaters)`
Where **id** will be used to identify which response belongs to which subscription.

You can get subscription updates by
    `Feed.Update(id,UpdateValueArgs)`

Comment: If you are doing multiple feeds subscriptions in a single event, isn't that in-and-of-itself violating single responsibility?  Each different event can be a cause to change the class rather than a single reason to change the class.

Comment: it's not me, it's the API. That's why I'm trying to make a class that will manage the subscriptions and notify the proper objects.  
To make it clearer, here's how the API is used. let's call the api Feed.  
`1. Feed.Connect() //establishes connection between the API and the program`  `2. Feed.Subscribe(id, SubscriptionParamaters) requests a feed`  Once you do that, the API will return any feed updates on one event which you need to subscribe to get incoming data. The event has the signature  `Feed.Updates(id,UpdateValueArgs)`